# How can I write this as implicit recursion?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a module that can take a string representation of a simple equation, and evaluate it. As a first step, I need to cut the equation into individual tokens; based on the "rules" of `takePiece`. I tried writing `cutEqu` as a fold, but ran into the problem that I'm not really folding over the string; I'm taking different sized pieces until it's exhausted. I could cheat and make it fold over a list of numbers equal to the length of the string, but that seems clumsy.

In most of the guides I've read, they note that explicit recursion is a rare occurrence once you understand implicit recursive patterns (like folds and maps), and this seems like a potentially common scenario, but can't find an appropriate standard function to handle it. How would someone go about writing something simple like `cutEqu` using implicit recursion? I'm sure I could figure out a simple function to encapsulate the behavior, but it not already existing in the standard library suggests that I may be thinking about the scenario wrong.

```
import Data.Char

isLit :: String -> Bool
isLit = isDigit . head

takePiece :: String -> (String,String)
takePiece str
    | isLit str = break (not . isDigit) str
    | otherwise = splitAt 1 str

cutEqu :: String -> [String]
cutEqu [] = []
cutEqu xs = let (p,rest) = takePiece xs in
            p : cutEqu rest
```

Edit:
Here's my attempt at writing it implicitly:

```
consumeWith :: ([a] -> ([b],[a])) -> [a] -> [[b]]
consumeWith _ [] = []
consumeWith f xs = let (t, rest) = f xs in
    t : consumeWith f rest

cutEqu' :: String -> [String]
cutEqu' = consumeWith (takePiece)
```

But again, I'm concerned that anything like this isn't a standard function. Is there a better way of going about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pattern is called `unfoldr` which has the type signature:

```
unfoldr :: (b -> Maybe (a, b)) -> b -> [a]
```

Your `cutEq` function can be written in terms of `unfoldr` like this:

```
import Data.List

cutEq' str = unfoldr go str
  where go [] = Nothing
        go xs = Just $ takePiece xs
```

Comment: Wow. Didn't consider that the signature might have a `Maybe` in it. I'm guessing that `Nothing` is the stop condition? And `unfold` seems kind of counter intuitive doesn't it? It doesn't seem like it's the opposite of a fold as it's name would suggest. Thanks though.

Comment: Actually, nevermind. I guess it starts with a value, and creates a list of values using a function, so that is the opposite of a fold.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think implicit vs. explicit recursion is the issue you should focus on here.  The first thing I'd advise you to do is to split this problem into two parts:

1. **Parsing:** Take the string and produce an *abstract syntax tree* ("AST") that represents the formula.
2. **Evaluation:** Take the AST and produce the result.

I can't tell from your code what is the structure of the equation language you're trying to implement here.  This is the place I'd start, not the parsing: defining the data type for the AST.  For example, here is an AST suitable for a simple expression language with variables, numeric literals, addition, subtraction and multiplication:

```
import Control.Applicative (liftA2)
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as Map

-- | The abstract syntax tree for the expression language.
data Expr a = Var String
            | Lit a
            | Add (Expr a) (Expr a)
            | Sub (Expr a) (Expr a)
            | Mul (Expr a) (Expr a)
    deriving Show


-- | Evaluate an 'Expr', using a 'Map' of variable names to values to represent the
-- evaluation environment.
eval :: Num a => Map String a -> Expr a -> Maybe a
eval env (Var v) = Map.lookup v env
eval env (Lit a) = Just a
eval env (Add expr1 expr2) = liftA2 (+) (eval env expr1) (eval env expr2)
eval env (Sub expr1 expr2) = liftA2 (-) (eval env expr1) (eval env expr2)
eval env (Mul expr1 expr2) = liftA2 (*) (eval env expr1) (eval env expr2)
```

Then to complete the implementation, you write a function with this signature:

```
parse :: String -> Maybe Expr
```

And I'd say that, in fact, explicit recursion on an AST type like `Expr` is a fine solution for a simple interpreter like this.  The "prefer implicit recursion" advice works better for collection types like lists, because it makes code easier to write and read.  But in the case of a simple AST-based interpreter, what you want to do is define the AST so that it serve as a scaffolding for writing simple evaluation rules that say how the value of an expression is related to the value of its subexpressions (known as [compositionality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_compositionality)).

Comment: I already have all of that defined; I just didn't include it because it didn't seem relevant to the question. Thank you for the mini guide though.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: Oh, ok.  The biggest piece of advice then would be to use a parser combinator library like [Parsec](https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=haskell+parsec+tutorial&gws_rd=ssl) instead of hand-rolling a parser.

Comment: I've been hesitant to use Parsec because honestly, it looks insanely messy, but I guess I might get used to it. Would you use a Parser for something this simple though?

Comment: The startup cost to learn the basics is higher, yes, but it's very much worth it in the long run, *particularly* for simple problems. Something that might help is to read a couple of papers explaining how parser combinators work; you might be able to avoid Parsec proper if you just copy the factoring it uses (basically, `String -> [(a, String)]`). See [Hutton & Meijer, "Monadic Parser Combinators"](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~gmh/monparsing.pdf), and [Swierstra
, "Combinator Parsing: A Short
Tutorial"](http://www.cs.uu.nl/research/techreps/repo/CS-2008/2008-044.pdf).

Comment: I wrote a mini-parser Monad instance, so I understand the basics, it's just always seemed like overkill. Maybe that's just something I'll have to get over. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: let me rephrase it this way. My take is that using the parser combinators will probably take more effort to *write*, but will make the code much, much more readable. This probably yields a useful criterion: if you or somebody else will be coming back later to read the code it will pay off. If you're writing throw-away code (famous last words!), then you may consider avoiding the cost.

Comment: OK, thanks. I rarely take the future into consideration given I'm not even in school yet, but I guess it's something I should begin thinking about.